# Constantly Execute function upon KeyDown

Tags: javascript

So, if you hold down a key, it would:

1. First input the key
2. Wait for `500ms`
3. Repeatedly input the key

Or like this:

```
a         a a a a a ....
|         |         |
0         500       1000
```

**I wanted to execute a code that executes a function constantly every x ms.**

I currently have this:

```
var flag = true;
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(){
    if(flag){
        flag = false;
        //code
        setTimeOut(function(){flag = true}, 500);
    }
})
```

But obviously that only works for `500ms` or more intervals. If I wanted a `100ms` interval, what should I do?

Comment: Does the thing you want happen when you set your timeout (or start your interval) on the `keydown` event instead of waiting for `keypress`?

Comment: @WanderNauta sorry, that was a mistake of re-typing my snippet of code

Comment: @WanderNauta but  `keydown` would also not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will run your tick function every 100ms while a key is down:

```
var intervalID;

function tick() {
    // code, for example:
    document.body.innerHTML += ".";
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(){
    if (!intervalID) intervalID = setInterval(tick, 100);
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
    clearInterval(intervalID);
    intervalID = undefined;
});
```

If you want to constantly execute the function forever, you don't need to keep the interval ID and you don't need the keyup handler.

https://jsfiddle.net/thsk1dpp/

Comment: Wow! I've never thought of this before! Learnt something new today, thanks! :D